# Run task in Before Build target

Tags: c#, msbuild-task

How cat i run my custom task in Before build target without pre-build events in Visual Studio?
for example

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  //pass parameters
  //run Task
</Target>
```

Comment: Is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293582.aspx) what you are looking for?

Comment: An example, If we want to copy a file then we can use the Copy task <Target Name="BeforeBuild"> 
       <Copy SourceFiles="c:\test.txt" DestinationFolder="d:\dest\"/> 
</Target>

Comment: And here is the list of tasks http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z253716.aspx